# Can't get 433 RF to work

Tags: arduino-mega, rf

I am trying to have two Arduino's to communicate to each other via 433Mhz units. My project is a bit more complex, but I since it was notworking I reduced it to most basic form in order to exclude the possibility of other issues.

Right now I have to Arduino Mega, a received and a transmiter. I am using the RadioHead library examples, to make sure my code is not to blame.

[image: Both Arduino's circuit]

I am using the example code:

Transmiter:

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h> 
 
RH_ASK rf_driver;
 
void setup()
{
    rf_driver.init();
}
 
void loop()
{
    const char *msg = "Hello World";
    rf_driver.send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
    rf_driver.waitPacketSent();
    delay(1000);
}
```

Receiver:

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h> 
 
RH_ASK rf_driver;
 
void setup()
{
    rf_driver.init();
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
 
void loop()
{
    uint8_t buf[11];
    uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf);
    if (rf_driver.recv(buf, &buflen))
    {
      Serial.print("Message Received: ");
      Serial.println((char*)buf);         
    }
}
```

Other notes:

- It seems the receiver works. I am using RC Switch sniffer and I can sniff other 433 remotes. But nothing coming from the sender

I already tried:

- Ordering new radio modules
- Variety of libraries: RadioHead, VirtualWire and a bunch of other things found online
- Uploading the code with Arduino Create and with Arduino IDE

Any suggestions on that else to try to figure out where I am failing would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need any library to transmit text. You can simply connect the transievers to the respective UART Tx and Rx pins and have the arduinos `Serial.print()` to each other (it's half duplex, though). Try this to see if the used library is to blame.

Comment: If you are using the WL102-341 transmitter, it's operating voltage spec is 2.0 - 3.6VDC.

Comment: @VE7JRO that was indeed the problem. On the seller website it specifies it works with anything from 3 to 12, but I moved it from 5 to 3.3 and now it works. Thank you!